# having error on javascript on adding the jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am a new learner learning javascript now. I have written to include the jquery in the head tag as the  following

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

it runs fine as the first time I compile the code in live server, but when I open it in like 3 hours later, it gives me the following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Refused to execute script from 'my local file address' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I have read some posts on the internet and am still unable to fix it. I tried to add the jquery script in another HTML file and it works fine, which makes me more confused. Please tell me how to fix the error. Thank you.

Comment: You should use your browser's "Network" debugging tab to determine exactly which script is failing with a 404.

Comment: The error you're encountering indicates that the browser is having trouble loading the jQuery script from the external source.

Comment: How about: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: And, you rather don't use `<script>` from HEAD in a render blocking manner. Place it rather right before the closing `</body>` tag. Or use `defer`.